# Rails Gemfile defaults to 'https' - 'bundle install' fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've noticed that when generating a new rails project, the Gemfile now defaults to:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`

instead of

`source 'http://rubygems.org'`

and now `bundle install` fails for me. When it attempts to run, I get:

`/Users/<my user name>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation fault`

If I manually change the Gemfile to `http`, then `bundle install` performs fine.

Is there an error with my setup (I've replicated this on two different boxes), or is there another issue I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably using MacPorts. It installs its own version of openssl, in addition to your local openssl, which causes issues. If that's the case, **[follow these instructions](http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/09/02/ruby-1-9-2-segmentation-fault-and-openssl/)**:

```
rvm remove ruby-1.9.3
rvm install ruby-1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/local
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this segfault previously when using a version of Ruby that was compiled against a different version of libssl-dev. That is, if you've updated libssl, but not libssl-dev, since building your rvm ruby, ruby will segfault when linking to libssl, since it was built with the wrong headers. What I did to fix it was make sure that libssl-dev was updated, nuke my ruby with `rvm remove`, and build it again.

EDIT: I knew I found more information about this somewhere. [Turns out it was on the RVM site itself](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/). I point rvm to the ssl I have installed with macports `--with-openssl-dir=/opt/local/usr/local`, personally.

Comment: There is also a more complete list of commands: https://rvm.io/integration/macports/